# Query evaluation took too long

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I am using GraphDB Free 7.1 and I have created a repository with the default settings. I have uploaded a ttl file with 2.7 million triplets. I am trying to issue a query (not very complex, but quite complex) that should return 200k answers and the Workbench displays just 1k answers and the GraphDB log displays an exception

```
10:52:19.580 [repositories/PaaSport] INFO  c.o.f.sesame.RepositoryController - POST query -1325396809
10:52:29.594 [repositories/PaaSport] ERROR o.o.h.s.r.TupleQueryResultView - Query interrupted
org.openrdf.query.QueryInterruptedException: Query evaluation took too long
...
10:52:29.594 [repositories/PaaSport] INFO  o.o.h.s.r.TupleQueryResultView - Request for query -1325396809 is finished
```

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?offering ?Value 
WHERE {
    ?offering           a                          paasport:Offering ; 
                        DUL:satisfies              ?groundDescription . 
    ?groundDescription  paasport:offers            ?characteristic . 
    ?characteristic     a                          paasport:Storage ; 
                        DUL:hasParameter           ?par . 
    ?par                a                          paasport:StorageCapacity ; 
                        DUL:hasParameterDataValue  ?Value ; 
                        DUL:parametrizes           ?qualityValue . 
    ?qualityValue       uomvocab:measuredIn        ?Units .
    ?Units              a                          ?AppParMeasureUnitType . 
    ucum:GB             a                          ?AppParMeasureUnitType . 
    ?Units              a                          uomvocab:SimpleDerivedUnit . 
    ucum:GB             a                          uomvocab:SimpleDerivedUnit . 
    ucum:GB             uomvocab:derivesFrom       ?BasicUnit . 
    ?Units              uomvocab:derivesFrom       ?BasicUnit . 
    ucum:GB             uomvocab:modifierPrefix    ?prefix1 . 
    ?Units              uomvocab:modifierPrefix    ?prefix2 . 
    ?prefix1            uomvocab:factor            ?Factor1 . 
    ?prefix2            uomvocab:factor            ?Factor2 . 
       FILTER( xsd:double(?Factor2)*?Value = xsd:double(?Factor1)*4) 
  }
```

Since the query timeout is set to 0, I am not sure what causes the query interruption exception; most probably memory problems?
Very simple queries (e.g. return all instances of a certain class) work OK.

Are there any hints? Any help would be appreciated.
I can provide more details if needed.

Best,
Nick

Comment: It looks like the query is too complex. Can you share the query? Did you try to change the order of some parts of the query? Sometimes this can help the query plan optimizer to choose a more efficient execution plan. In addition, there might be some GraphDB config params, but I'm not an expert in this triple store.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?offering ?Value WHERE {

        ?offering rdf:type  paasport:Offering .

 ?offering DUL:satisfies ?groundDescription .

 ?groundDescription paasport:offers ?characteristic .

 ?characteristic rdf:type paasport:Storage  .

 ?characteristic DUL:hasParameter ?par .

 ?par rdf:type paasport:StorageCapacity .

 ?par DUL:hasParameterDataValue ?Value .

 ?par DUL:parametrizes ?qualityValue .

 ?qualityValue uomvocab:measuredIn ?Units .`

Comment: `?Units rdf:type ?AppParMeasureUnitType .

 ucum:GB rdf:type ?AppParMeasureUnitType .

 ?Units rdf:type uomvocab:SimpleDerivedUnit .

 ucum:GB rdf:type uomvocab:SimpleDerivedUnit .

 ucum:GB uomvocab:derivesFrom ?BasicUnit .

 ?Units uomvocab:derivesFrom ?BasicUnit .

 ucum:GB uomvocab:modifierPrefix ?prefix1 .

 ?Units uomvocab:modifierPrefix ?prefix2 .

 ?prefix1 uomvocab:factor ?Factor1 .

 ?prefix2 uomvocab:factor ?Factor2 .

     FILTER( xsd:double(?Factor2)*?Value = xsd:double(?Factor1)*4)

}`

Comment: Thank you. One comment: It's more readable if you edit your question...I did it for you now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have managed to cut down the query to the minimum, in order to be answered. The problem was mainly due to the following triple patterns:

```
ucum:GB  rdf:type              ?AppParMeasureUnitType .
ucum:GB  rdf:type              uomvocab:SimpleDerivedUnit .
ucum:GB  uomvocab:derivesFrom  ?BasicUnit .
```

If these are omitted and the corresponding variables in the original query are replaced by constant resources, then the query is answered.

Here is the resulting query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?offering ?Value 
WHERE {
    ?offering           rdf:type                   paasport:Offering .
    ?offering           DUL:satisfies              ?groundDescription .
    ?groundDescription  paasport:offers            ?characteristic .
    ?characteristic     rdf:type                   paasport:Storage  .
    ?characteristic     DUL:hasParameter           ?par .
    ?par                rdf:type                   paasport:StorageCapacity .
    ?par                DUL:hasParameterDataValue  ?Value .
    ?par                DUL:parametrizes           ?qualityValue .
    ?qualityValue       uomvocab:measuredIn        ?Units .
    ?Units              rdf:type                   ucum:UnitOf-infotech .
    ?Units              rdf:type                   uomvocab:SimpleDerivedUnit .
    ?Units              uomvocab:derivesFrom       <http://purl.oclc.org/NET/muo/ucum/unit/amount-of-information/byte> .
    ucum:GB             uomvocab:modifierPrefix    ?prefix1 .
    ?Units              uomvocab:modifierPrefix    ?prefix2 .
    ?prefix1            uomvocab:factor            ?Factor1 .
    ?prefix2            uomvocab:factor            ?Factor2 .
        FILTER( xsd:double(?Factor2)*?Value >= xsd:double(?Factor1)*2)
}
```

Comment: Ok, but does this query has the same meaning as the original query? I don't think so, am I right? But sure, if you know the bindings of those variables, you can reduce the number of joins.

Comment: The bindings to the variables can be pre-determined by simpler SPARQL queries and then the big one can be constructed. Nevertheless, the query still times-out at the next "testing level" of 27million triples.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you really need DISTINCT? That always slows down things, since it has to fetch all results in memory, sort them and uniq them before starting to serve.
2. Do you need = or >= in the FILTER? If = then replace the filter with a BIND(...as ?Factor2), and put these things before searching for ?prefix2
3. Have you profiled the query? http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/explain-plan.html